# SAP GUI automation in macOS

Tags: macos, automation, scripting, sap-gui

I am trying to do SAP GUI scripting on macOS but I struggle to find up to date ressources / tutorials to help me. I found that [user guide](http://www.synactive.com/download/sap%20gui%20scripting/sap%20gui%20scripting%20userguide.pdf)  but it seems that Apple Script does not support SAP GUI anymore : there is no dictionary available and the record script feature does not work with the SAP GUI. I am on macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and I use SAP GUI 7.50rev1

Would someone have some ressources to share ?

Thanks a lot, Ludovic.

Comment: `pyautogui` may be a possibility... https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#purpose

Comment: Thanks a for the hint @MarkSetchell. I am affraid that `pyautogui` would be unstable. I hope to find something working with `session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[18,15]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[18,15]").caretPosition = 10`